# Why C array has extra bytes at tail?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-alignment

I examine that C array maybe have some extra bytes at tail.

There are my code

```
int a = 5;
int test[] = {1,2,3,4};
int b = 5;

test[-1] = 11;
test[4] = 11;

cout << b << endl; // 11 
cout << a << endl; // 5
```

You can see the running result [there](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Wp555Rr0TxId1G2R)

the value of `b` is changed through changing `test[-1]`'s value. But when I change `test[4]`'s value, the value of `a` doesn't change;

I use gdb to check their addresses, found that

In g++ 6.4.0, the address of `a` substract address of `test[4]` is 8 bytes
In clang++ 3.8.1, the address of `a` substract address of `test[4]` is 4 bytes

So, I am curious that why the array has some bytes at tail?

Thanks @Peter A.Schneider to explaining the question. 
It is surely a UB , But it is just a experimental code.  This isn't a discuss for practical code.

generally，variables at the runtime stack are close together. `b` is close to test， but why 'a' is not close to 'test+3'. That's the key of the problem.

Comment: `test[-1] = 11;` - ? -1 for an index

Comment: You cannot call _undefined behavior_ and expect a specific one.

Comment: Your code has UB. That's it.

Comment: There are no syntax errors so it does compile. You can try with gcc

Comment: That's not C code.

Comment: @cyhone Did anyone talk about syntax errors?

Comment: The compiler assigns aligned addresses to variables and arrays on the stack. This is why there is a difference between g++ and clang.  Some debug builds can also have buffer zones around arrays to detect out of range assignments.

Comment: @user0042 It is undefined behavior per the C++ standard; but any given compiler will usually produce the same code for the program in subsequent compilations, and executing that code will likely produce the same result, each time. That means: The behavior on a given system is not (officially) defined but usually predictable. If we understand the author's question to be about a specific system it's a legit question.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider And that's useful for exactly what again please?

Comment: @user0042 It's just a experimental code

Comment: @user0042 Understanding compilers and CPUs and bugs? Exploiting, well, stack overflows? Hacking? *Preventing* the bugs?

Answer (score 5):

```
test[-1] = 11;
test[4] = 11;
```

This is undefined behavior.(Meaning anything could have happened). In your case you changed the value of `b` because they are adjacent in the memory where they are allocated. But you shouldn't rely on it. Because this may blow up your program or results in erroneous code behavior most of the time.

The UB you have is because *`Accessing an array index out of bound in undefined behavior."*

Comment: You should mention also the rule why this is undefined behaviour (accessing an array out of its bounds is UB)

Comment: @LoPiTaL.: Yes Edited.